# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: itemData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

I am developing a Meals App refering to a React Native - The Practical Guide [2023]
course in Udemy. While using a native route prop i am facin with the mentioned error i.e can't find itemData
Can some help me to figure out where this code is going wrong.

CategoriesScreen.js

```
import { FlatList, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { CATEGORIES } from "../data/dummy-data";
import CategoryGridTile from "../components/CategoryGridTile";

function CategoriesScreen({ navigation }) {
  function pressHandler() {
    navigation.navigate("Meals Overview", { categoryId: itemData.item.id, });
  }
  function renderCategoryItem(itemData) {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        title={itemData.item.title}
        color={itemData.item.color}
        onPress={pressHandler}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={CATEGORIES}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={renderCategoryItem}
      numColumns={2}
    />
  );
}
export default CategoriesScreen;
```

MealsOverviewScreen

```
import { View,Text,StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {MEALS} from "../data/dummy-data"
function MealsOverviewScreen({route}){
    const catId=route.params.categoryId;
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Meals Overview Screen - {catId}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export default MealsOverviewScreen;
const styles=StyleSheet.create(
    {
        container:{
            flex:1,
            padding:16,
        }
    }
)
```

CategoryGridTile.js

```
import { Pressable, View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native";

function CategoryGridTile({ title, color,onPress}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.gridItem}>
      <Pressable
        style={({ pressed }) => [styles.buttonStyle,pressed?styles.buttonPressed:null,]}
        android_ripple={{ color: "#ccc" }}
        onPress={onPress}   
      >
        <View style={[styles.innerContainer,{backgroundColor:color }]}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
}
export default CategoryGridTile;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridItem: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 16,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 8,
    elevation: 4,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 8,
    overflow: Platform.OS == "android" ? "hidden" : "visible",
  },
  buttonPressed: {
    opacity: 0.25,
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  innerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
    borderRadius:8,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});
```

Comment: I don't know this Udemy course, but I can see that in your pressHandler function, you will use this itemData variable. Where is value come from? Do you have a state with this value? Probably the error is there.

Comment: `itemData` is not in the scope of the `pressHandler` function. You can do something like this: define `pressHandler` as `function pressHandler(itemData) { .. }` and then use `onPress={() => pressHandler(itemData)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in `pressHandler` function . There is no `itemData` variable declared and initialised in function but still you are trying to use it ..

You can change code in `CategoriesScreen` function created in `CategoriesScreen.js` as mentioned below

From

```
function renderCategoryItem(itemData) {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        title={itemData.item.title}
        color={itemData.item.color}
        onPress={pressHandler}
      />
    );
  }
```

To

```
function renderCategoryItem(itemData) {
    return (
      <CategoryGridTile
        title={itemData.item.title}
        color={itemData.item.color}
        onPress={()=>{
           pressHandler(itemData)
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```

From

```
function pressHandler() {
    navigation.navigate("Meals Overview", { categoryId: itemData.item.id, });
  }
```

To

```
function pressHandler(itemData) {
    navigation.navigate("Meals Overview", { categoryId: itemData.item.id, });
  }
```